Can we mark a question as answered, if the OP has abandoned it?
A lot of users ask a question and then abandon the Computer Graphics Stackexchange alltogether. This leaves a lot of questions "unanswered", although in some cases there seems to be a good answer for OP's question.
See for example:

Optimisation of Geometry Pass
How to calculate position from depth pass of the ZED camera?

In some cases, users answer their own question (good!) but don't mark the question as answered (not good!).
See for example:

Efficiently generating mesh for self-generated voxel grid
Am I creating my raygeneration shader correctly

In theory this may not be the end of the world, but the community bot keeps pulling these questions to the front. I find this to be somewhat annoying.
Can we mark questions as answered, if it is obvious that the OP has abandoned a question and there is a viable answer, or if they answered themselves without accepting?
To be clear, my question is not so much "are we allowed to" but more "can we get a tool to do so".
Since I don't do a whole lot of moderating, I don't know if other boards have this. I also don't want to overrule the OP - if they decide it is unanswered, they should be able to remove the moderated acceptance.

I'm less familiar with the culture here, but on the Game Dev Stack Exchange, sometimes mods or active community members will nudge users to accept their own answers. Anecdotally, this seems to happen more with new users, probably on the assumption that they're less familiar with the Stack Exchange model. It's easy to overlook though - there's a built in 48 hour wait & I imagine sometimes people just forget to double back and check it off.
I'm not in a position to say whether or not such a system could be put in place. Speaking for myself, there are other feature requests that I'd prefer.
